# How do you prevent character escaping in knockout.js data-binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascript-framework, knockout-2.0, html-escape-characters

This code displays the non-breaking space escape sequence instead of the actual spaces:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var modelType = function() {
          this.A = ko.observable('a b&nbsp;&nbsp;c');
        };
        var model = new modelType();
        ko.applyBindings(model);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p data-bind="text: A"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

It displays the following:

```
a b&nbsp;&nbsp;c
```

instead of

```
a b  c
```

How do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `html` binding instead of `text`:

```
<p data-bind="html: A"></p>
```

Comment: and for options ?  `ie <select data-bind='options:myData'></select>`

Comment: @e10 Did you ever find out how to do this for options?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the html binding, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html:

```
<p data-bind="html: A"></p>
```